# "Looking forward to hearing from you" - May I omit "I am" at the beginning?

Tags: politeness, ellipsis, conversational-deletion

At the end of a letter, is it correct to omit "I am" in this sentence?

> I am looking forward to hearing from you

Then it will become:

> Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Looking forward to hearing from you” is a written representation of *Conversational Deletion*, which John Lawler has treated on ELU: [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58445/24489), for instance, and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/24489). This term names the very common colloquial omission of anything at the front of a sentence which can in context be taken for granted.

Because this is a colloquial practice, it should be used only in letters to people with whom you are on familiar terms: friends, family, or business and professional associates with whom you have a long and friendly history. Do not use it with correspondents whom you do not know well. Use the full form instead; or for just a touch more formality use the simple present:

> I look forward to hearing from you.