# Omission of subject -- Can we omit 'it' (subjective) in any cases?

Tags: subjects

Following are a few examples;

1. (It) Looks like you didn't study much for the test.
2. (It) Seems like I'm the third wheel here.

Are the above omissions valid either formally or informally? How so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Looking forward to hearing from you" - May I omit "I am" at the beginning?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/looking-forward-to-hearing-from-you-may-i-omit-i-am-at-the-beginning). You may see other questions on this topic under the tag [tag:conversational-deletion].

Comment: @StoneyB These kinda conversational-deletions are informal always, right?

Comment: That's right. Like *kinda*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The omission of the *dummy pronoun* "it" in the subject position is valid and relatively common in speech. This is addressed in *The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) in Chapter 17 §7.8.1. *Ellipsis of grammaticised word at the beginning of a main clause*. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> A range of grammaticised items, such as personal pronouns and auxiliaries, can be omitted at the beginning of a main clause in casual style. In general this type of ellipsis is not dependent on the presence of an antecedent.
>
> (a) Ellipsis of personal pronoun as subject
>
> ... 
>   ii. *Doesn't matter.* *Serves you right.* *Must be time for bed, isn't it?*
>
> ... 
>   This occurs mainly with 1st person *I* and the dummy pronouns *it* and *there*, as in these examples.

Answer (score 1):

Those omissions are definitely valid, and you hear that kind of construction a lot in informal speaking. It's called "conversational deletion"; essentially you can omit any word or combination of words at the beginning of a sentence as long as the sentence still makes sense in context.

Just to reiterate though, this should only ever be used when speaking / writing informally. It is not grammatically "correct" and therefore should never be used when writing in a formal / professional context.

Comment: I bet you will get a lot of comments here but yes, conversational deletion is right on.

Comment: @JessSTJ Are conversational-deletions always informal?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli As far as I know, yes. Even informal writing doesn't use them that much; it's a lot more common in spoken English.